# Adding mouselistener to canvas with lwjgl display on it

Tags: java, lwjgl, mouselistener

I'm using java and LWJGL. I created a mouse listener for a canvas, but when I set the Displays parent to the canvas it doesn't work.

The mousehandlerClass:

```
private static class handlerClass implements MouseListener {
    public handlerClass() {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Canvas clicked");
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Here is where I set the canvas as parent in my DisplayManager class:

```
public void createDisplayJFrame(Canvas canvas) {
    ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 2).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        Display.setParent(canvas);
        Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);

    } catch (LWJGLException ex) {
        //System.out.println(ex);
    }
    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    lastFrameTime = getCurrentTime();
}
```

Here is where I add the MouseListener:

```
public class UIMain extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form UIMain
 */
private static Canvas canvas;
public static DisplayThread dt;
HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();

public UIMain() {
    initComponents();
    canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.addMouseListener(handler);
    canvas.setSize(500, 500);
    canvas.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.isDisplayable();
    canvas.setVisible(true);
    jPanel2.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

My DisplayThreadClass:

```
public class DisplayThread extends Thread {

private Canvas canvas;
ArrayList<Entity> entities = new ArrayList();

public DisplayThread(Canvas canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
}

public void run() {
    new DisplayManager().createDisplayJFrame(canvas);
    //Created entities and added to entities
    ......
    MasterRenderer renderer = new MasterRenderer();
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
        //Here is the solution   if(org.lwjgl.input.Mouse.isButtonDown(org.lwjgl.input.Mouse.getEventButton())){
            System.out.println("Mouse was clicked");
        }
    }
    renderer.cleanUp();
    DisplayManager.closeDisplay();
}
```

When the canvas is not set as the parent (Nothing on the canvas) then the mouseListener works. But when the displays parent is set to the canvas. It does nothing. How can I determine when the mouse is clicked on the canvas when the canvas is set as parent?

Comment: 1) Use a `MouseAdapter` instead. 2) Class names should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: What are is `Display`? Where do you add the mouse listener?

Comment: @user1803551 http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html this is what Display is.

Comment: Alright, you're going to have to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's explained in the link in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the actual issue may be resolved: This is probably related to some "magic" that is done in LWJGL, and may be related to [LWJGL Display mounted on Canvas fails to generate Mouse Events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8460514/3182664) - so if you used a `Frame` instead of a `JFrame`, it should already work.

However, if you want to use swing, and add a real `MouseListener` to the canvas, you can consider using an LWJGL [`AWTGLCanvas`](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/AWTGLCanvas.html):

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.AWTGLCanvas;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;

public class LwjglCanvasMouseEvents
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        LwjglCanvas canvas = null;
        try
        {
            canvas = new LwjglCanvas();
        }
        catch (LWJGLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        });
        f.getContentPane().add(canvas);
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class LwjglCanvas extends AWTGLCanvas
{
    private int currentWidth;
    private int currentHeight;

    public LwjglCanvas() throws LWJGLException
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintGL()
    {
        if (getWidth() != currentWidth || getHeight() != currentHeight)
        {
            currentWidth = getWidth();
            currentHeight = getHeight();
            glViewport(0, 0, currentWidth, currentHeight);
        }
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluOrtho2D(0.0f, currentWidth, 0.0f, currentHeight);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glPushMatrix();

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(200, 0, 0);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(100, 200, 0);
        glEnd();

        glPopMatrix();
        try
        {
            swapBuffers();
        }
        catch (LWJGLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using in my displayThread

```
if(org.lwjgl.input.Mouse.isButtonDown(org.lwjgl.input.Mouse.getEventButton())){
    System.out.println("Mouse was clicked");
}
```

LWJGL can check if the mouse is pressed.